# How to automatically process multiple "goals"?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-lifecycle

I use `package` to have Maven generate the target JAR-file, and the `dependency:build-classpath` to generate the `cp.txt` listing all of the dependency JARs, that I don't want bundled into the target JAR:

`mvn package dependency:build-classpath`

Is there a way to make the classpath building happen together with the packaging *automatically* -- without me explicitly requesting both on command-line?

Comment: Just add the plugin to your POM, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:build-classpath

Comment: Why you are calling build-classpath? Maybe using exec-maven-plugin is easier https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Comment: I'm calling `dependency:build-classpath`, because I found that somewhere -- and it worked without me doing any changes to the `pom.xml` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command below executes the `build-classpath` goal of the maven `dependency` plugin:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

But when with the command below you actually instruct maven to pass from  all the phases, up to `package` phase, on the [default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.4/maven-core/lifecycles.html#default_Lifecycle) (to which `package` phase belongs). When maven passes from these phases it executes all the attached plugin goals:

```
mvn package
```

However, maven does not by default attach the `dependency:build-classpath` goal to any phase (though it does with some other goals depending on type of packaging). You need to explicitly do this, just by declaring the plugin goal to the `pom.xml` (also providing the corresponding configuration):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-classpath</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>cp.txt</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Maven will then attach the above goal to the `generate-sources` phase (which is [the goal's default phase](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html)) and when that phase comes, the `dependency:build-classpath` plugin goal will execute.

**Conclusion:**

Q: How to automatically process multiple "goals"?

A: You declare these goals to `pom.xml` (and optionally override the default each goal attaches to, e.g. in case you want to change their order of execution) and when maven passes from that phase, as part of [maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.4/maven-core/lifecycles.html), they will automatically execute.